# Can we take three laptops?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, airport-security, hand-luggage

I along with my family(total 4 members) will be travelling to India soon(from Dubai). We have total 3 laptops to take to India which we each use for our personal use. I want to know if I will be charged with custom duty.

PS: Since we are travelling as a family I fear that there may be any problems. We are 3 adults, so I want to be sure about the no duty for all of us three.

Comment: How long will you be staying in India? Where do your normally reside? Where did you purchase the laptops?

Comment: I will stay for a month. I purchased all the laptops from my current residential place, UAE.